# SQL Query that suggest next quizes of every user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

```
quiz table 
=================
id, q_name, code


completed_quizes table
======================================================
id, completion_date, user_id, quiz_code, quiz_count
```

I have 2 types of quizes

```
Table_name: quiz_names
id     q_name              code
1      grand_quiz          gra
2      normal_quiz         nor

Table_name: completed_quizes
id    completion_date         user_id      q_code   q_count
1     1340841600 (28June2012)    2          gra       0
2     1340755200(27June2012)     2          nor       3
3     1340668800(26June2012)     2          nor       2
4     1340582400(25June2012)     2          nor       1
5     1340496000(24June2012)     2          gra       0
6     1340841600 (28June2012)    3          gra       0
7     1340755200(27June2012)     3          nor       3
8     1340668800(26June2012)     3          nor       2
9     1340582400(25June2012)     3          nor       1
10    1340496000(24June2012)     3          gra       0
```

Rules:

1- first of all all users grand quiz will be taken.

2- based on grand quiz, if any user last quiz was grand quiz then next suggestion will be normal quiz 1.

3- based on normal quiz 1 , if any user last quiz was normal quiz 1 then next suggestion will be normal quiz 2.

4- based on normal quiz 2 , if any user last quiz was normal quiz 2 then next suggestion will be normal quiz 3.

5- if any users last quiz was normal quiz 3 then again grand quiz will be next suggestion.

**P.S**

Problem is that every users next suggestion is based upon his previous completed quiz. I want all users who's what will be the next quiz?

Any advice please?

Comment: please provide schema on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @JonEgerton: I have tried to get last done quiz of any user, but do't know how to make next upcomming on based on it!

Comment: @SashiKant: I have tried but code is not recognizing having problem Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'code' in 'field list'""

Comment: have edited my query, try now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) to obtain the latest quiz performed by each user, then add 1 (using [`MOD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) to rotate back to 0 those who've most recently taken quiz 3).  To include users who have not yet taken any quiz, you need to make an [outer join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) with your user table:

```
SELECT user_id, IFNULL((q_count+1) % 4, 0) AS next
FROM   users LEFT JOIN (
  completed_quizes NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT   user_id, MAX(completion_date) AS completion_date
    FROM     completed_quizes
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) AS t
) USING (user_id)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86b10/1).

Comment: after the normal quiz 3 then again their is next upcomming for grand quiz?

Comment: query executed successfully, but the problem is that it shows upcomming as 0 for all!

Comment: Thanks a lot such an effort, Dear again next is always 0, any thought please

Comment: @Aryans: As you can see from the sqlfiddle to which I link, the query works fine.  Your problem must lay elsewhere.  Please provide further information, or update sqlfiddle with your data in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Our sub query returns true completion date that is required but in my it returns incorect acordling info e.g count of previous one?

Comment: @Aryans: I'm sorry, but I don't understand.  Could you put some sample input/output somewhere that I can see it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13206/discussion-between-aryans-and-eggyal)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
select 
q_code, 
CASE 
WHEN q_code='gra'
THEN 'nor1'
ELSE IF q_code='nor3'
THEN 'gr'
ELSE
CONCAT('nor',CAST(MAX(q_count+1) as CHAR))
END as suggestion

from completed_quizes group by user_id
```

Comment: type cast the MAX(q_count+1) to String